# Tool to convert email communication into a support ticketing system

Tags: open-source, software-development, email-server

Hello Good Developers,

In my organisation, the Operations Team shares a common email account (POP3). All our clients send bids on that email and the team members process it (Replies) and move them in an outlook folder.

We use a self-hosted solution of Postfix server in a Ubuntu environment.

Sometimes because of so many emails in the queue; few mails goes unnoticed or moved without any action.

I am looking for something that can intercept all mails that we receive and opens a ticket and that ticket automatically gets resolved when there is an action taken (Or reply made).

I understand this may be organisation specific custom requirement but just trying to figure out if there is any way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if a web service is an option for you, but we use [FreshDesk](https://freshdesk.com/) - there is also a free plan.

Important features for us are:

- Tickets can be created by mail, api call or by an embed form
- You see if somebody is viewing or replying to the ticket
- Merging of similar tickets
- Assign tickets to people / groups